# Python requests failing with Failed to Establish new Connection Error 10061

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to access an api with key provided to me. here is the code.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
urletf='https://someapi'
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
resp_mf = s.get(urletf, params={"key":"somekey" }, stream=True)
content = resp_mf.content
```

This gives me error as :Failed to establish connection

[image]

when I try the URL in the browser or Postman I get response back.

https://someapi?key=myKey

Any idea why Python is giving error? I am expecting json back (if it matters) Thanks for help.

Comment: You behind a proxy or something? Check if env variable ``HTTP_PROXY`` is set.

Comment: Are you connecting to a website without a valid certificate? Or a certificate without a chain of trust? That seems to be the source of what's going on since the uri works in the browser.

Comment: HTTP_PROXY is not set . when I run
Set HTTP_PROXY, I get message as 

Environment variable HTTP_PROXY not defined

Comment: A note if I request with Proxies then it gives me response. 

eg: 
proxies = {'http://10.20.1.128': 'http://10.10.1.10:5323'}

resp_mf = s.get(urletf, params={"key":"somekey" }, stream=True, proxies = proxies ) gives me good response. 

Why is that? Is that something API provider should fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company has a proxy and I had to use it to access the api.

This code works.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
proxies = {<someproxy>}
urletf='https://someapi'
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
resp_mf = s.get(urletf, params={"key":"somekey" },proxies=proxies, stream=True)
content = resp_mf.content
```

Comment: Similarly I had to switch on the VPN that my company uses and the request worked